# Spring batch with Spring Boot terminates before children process with AsyncItemProcessor

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Batch with a AsyncItemProcessor and things are behaving unexpectedly. Let me show first the code:

Followed a simple example as shown on the [Spring Batch project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/):

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({HttpClientConfigurer.class, BatchJobConfigurer.class})
public class PerfilEletricoApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {// NOSONAR
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(PerfilEletricoApp.class, args)));
        //SpringApplication.run(PerfilEletricoApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

-- EDIT

If I just sleep the main process go give a few seconds to slf4j to write the flush the logs, everything works as expected.

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({HttpClientConfigurer.class, BatchJobConfigurer.class})
public class PerfilEletricoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {// NOSONAR
        //System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(PerfilEletricoApp.class, args)));
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(PerfilEletricoApp.class, args);

        Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context));
    }
```

}

-- ENDOF EDIT

I'm reading a text file with a field and then using a AsyncItemProcessor to get a multithreaded processing, which consists of a Http GET on a URL to fetch some data, I'm also using a NoOpWriter to do nothing on the write part. I'm saving the results of the GET on the Processor part of the job (using log.trace / log.warn).

```
@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfigurer {
    // [... property and configs omitted] 
    @Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient createHttpClient() {
      // ... creates and returns a poolable http client etc
    }
}
```

As for the Job:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchJobConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Value("${async.tps:10}")
    private Integer tps;

    @Value("${com.bemobi.perfilelerico.sourcedir:/AppServer/perfil-eletrico/source-dir/}")
    private String sourceDir;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<String> reader() {
        MultiResourceItemReader<String> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        reader.setResources( new Resource[] { new FileSystemResource(sourceDir)});
        reader.setDelegate((ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<? extends String>) flatItemReader());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<String> flatItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<String> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<String>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] { "sample-field-001"});
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new SimpleStringFieldSetMapper<>());
        }});
        return itemReader;
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor(){
        AsyncItemProcessor<String, OiPaggoResponse> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(processor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<String,OiPaggoResponse> processor(){
        return new PerfilEletricoItemProcessor();
    }

    /**
     * Using a NoOpItemWriter<T> so we satisfy spring batch flow but don't use writer for anything else.
     * @return a NoOpItemWriter<OiPaggoResponse>
     */
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<OiPaggoResponse> writer() {
        return new NoOpItemWriter<>();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step1() throws Exception {
/*
 Problem starts here, If Use the processor() everything ends nicely, but if I insist on the asyncItemProcessor(), the job ends and the logs from processor are not stored on the disk.
*/
        return this.steps.get("step1").<String, OiPaggoResponse> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())   
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("consulta-perfil-eletrico").start(step1()).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor()
    {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(tps);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(tps);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(tps * 1000);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncExecutor-");
        return executor;
    }
}
```

-- UPDATED WITH AsyncItemWriter (Working version)

```
   /*Wrapped Writer*/
   @Bean
    public ItemWriter asyncItemWriter(){
        AsyncItemWriter<OiPaggoResponse> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(writer());
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    /*AsyncItemWriter defined on the steps*/
    @Bean
    protected Step step1() throws Exception {
        return this.steps.get("step1").<String, OiPaggoResponse> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .writer(asyncItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

--
Any thoughts on why the AsyncItemProcessor don't wait for all the children to to complete before send a OK-Completed signal to the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the `AsyncItemProcessor` is creating `Future`s that no one is waiting for.  Wrap your `NoOpItemWriter` in the `AsyncItemWriter` so that someone is waiting for the `Future`s.  That will cause the job to complete as expected.

Comment: Michael, that looked so simple thanks a lot. I've create the NoOpWriter and not for a second stopped to think about that had been created on the AsyncItemProcessor. Thanks a million for that.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. Got the exact same issue using AsyncItemProcessor and NoOpItemWriter in config. To `wrap NoOpItemWriter` and use it `as delegate in AsyncItemWriter` have fixed the issue.